# Is it possible to use @PrePersist and @PreUpdate with eBean and Play! 2.0?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I want to know if is it possible to use `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` with `Ebean` and Play! 2.0. If so how is this feature activated. I've seen that there was a [pull request](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/pull/113) adding this feature a month ago, but I can't make this work on Play 2.0.

Thanks

Comment: According to https://github.com/playframework/Play20/pull/113 it should be possible with BeanPersistListener, although I dont know, how to configure it in Play2.

Answer (score 10):

If your goal is just setting createdAt or updatedAt fields, and you're using EBean, try `@CreatedTimestamp` and `@UpdatedTimestamp`.  See [here](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/index.html).  I'd prefer to use Biesior's approach, but it seemed to fail on Cascades -- the methods were never called.

```
@Column(name="created_at")
@CreatedTimestamp
private Date createdAt;

@Column(name="updated_at")
@UpdatedTimestamp
private Date updatedAt;
```

Answer (score 4):

Not a direct answer, but you can simulate these features by overriding  methods of `Model` class in your model, sample:

```
public class Post extends Model {

    // .... 

    @Override
    public void save() {
        this.createDate = new Date();
        this.modifyDate = new Date();
        super.save();
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Object o) {
        this.modifyDate = new Date();
        super.update(o);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems the way to go is to implement the [BeanPersistController](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/event/BeanPersistController.html), which offers Pre- and Post-Processing options.

To configure it in Play, modify the `application.conf` file, [as such](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/egUHpBsp6QI/jGU2B7jfpNoJ):

`ebean.default="models.*,models.adapters.YourPersistController"`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm really late on this but you can use this : https://gist.github.com/1547244 . You will need to register this Class in you application.conf like this :

```
ebean.default="models.*, models.sgcore.SGBeanPersistController"
```